# Switch column values to the left

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like below:

```
      Column A           Column B            Column C
     ----------          ---------         -----------
         1                   1                 2
         4                   3                 4
         3                  null               2
         12                  12                12
         15                  7                 7 
         8                   9                 6
         null                2                 2
         null                null              3
```

I need to move each column value from right to the left until each column have distinct values except the null values. Output must be like this:

```
      Column A           Column B            Column C
     ----------          ---------         -----------
         1                   2                null
         4                   3                null
         3                   2                null
         12                  null             null
         15                  7                null 
         8                   9                6
         2                   null             null
         3                   null             null
```

How can I do this with the simplest way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regexp_substr as follows:

Table data:

```
SQL> select a,b,c from t;

   A    B    C
---- ---- ----
   1    1    2
   4    3    4
   3         2
  12   12   12
  15    7    7
   8    9    6
        2    2
             3

8 rows selected.
```

Your query:

```
SQL> select regexp_substr(vals,'[^,]+',1,1) as a,
  2         regexp_substr(vals,'[^,]+',1,2) as b,
  3         regexp_substr(vals,'[^,]+',1,3) as c
  4    from (select rtrim(case when a is not null then a || ',' end ||
  5     case when b = a or b is null then null else b || ',' end ||
  6     case when b = c or a = c or c is null then null else c end, ',') as vals
  7    from t
  8  );

A   B   C
--- --- ---
1   2
4   3
3   2
12
15  7
8   9   6
2
3

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

This combination of unpivot, pivot and conditional ordering returns desired output:

```
with 
  nn as (
   select id, col, case rn when 1 then val end val
   from (
     select id, col, val, row_number() over (partition by id, val order by col) rn
     from (select rownum id, a, b, c from t)
     unpivot (val for col in (a, b, c) ) ) ),
   mov as (
     select id, val, 
            row_number() over (partition by id 
                               order by case when val is not null then col end ) rn 
     from nn )
select * from mov pivot (max(val) for rn in (1 a, 2 b, 3 c))
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4d745f1d2b9a56b16e116cffedc3f81d)

Subquery `nn` removes duplicated values, subquery `mov` based on conditional ordering moves them up. Then pivot transposes rows into columns, because they were unpivoted in first step.

Comment: In principle the base table may have rows where all three columns are `null`, and presumably those rows should still be present in the output. Your query, as written, will remove them from the output. That can be fixed, but it requires some care; simply using the `include nulls` option to `unpivot` is not enough. (Try it on the sample data to understand why.)

Comment: @mathguy `include nulls` is enough: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e3f82b2d2217c4a6bd6d3d48b1cebf0d). Thanks for noticing it.

Comment: No, it is not enough. I suggested that you try it **on the sample data** to understand why. I meant the same sample data the OP provided, and you tested on. Specifically, notice what happens on an input like `(null, 2, 2)`. You can see one way to completely fix the issue (rather than only partially) in the second solution in my answer.

Comment: Which sample data? Tested on OP's examples, added full null row and (null, 2, 2). Everything works as expected: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5aa94f11620fac12c1f470815067f54b).Logic is OK, query works for any number of columns. I would be grateful if you did not use the mentor tone in the conversation. I test my answers before I post them.

Answer (score 1):

If the input (and output) is three columns, as in your example, then a bit of brute force can give you an efficient query:

```
select coalesce(a, b, c)                                 as a
     , case when b != a                       then b
            when c != coalesce(a, b)          then c end as b
     , case when a != b and b != c and a != c then c end as c
from   t
;
```

It takes just a moment's thought to understand why this is correct (or, alternatively,  you can throw a lot of test cases at it and be satisfied that since it gives the correct answer in all cases, it *must* be correct even if you don't understand *why* it is).

This is not easy to generalize though; if you had, say, eight columns in the input (and in the output), you would do better with a solution like Ponder Stibbons proposed. Note, though, that the number of columns (whether it is three or eight or 250) has to be known in advance for a standard SQL query; otherwise you will need to write a dynamic query, which is generally not seen as a good practice.

**EDIT**:

Here is a solution that generalizes easily to any number of columns (same in the input and in the output); the number of columns, though, must be known in advance (as well as the *names* of the columns and their order).

This solution is similar to the one posted by Ponder Stibbons. There are two main differences. First, I use the `lateral` clause, which is available in Oracle 12.1 and higher; this allows computations to be done separately in each row (instead of mixing all values from all rows together after `unpivot`, only to group them back into the initial rows via `pivot`). Second, the code is a bit more complicated, to handle the case when all values in a row are `null`.

```
select l.a, l.b, l.c
from   t,
  lateral (
    select a, b, c
    from   ( select  1, row_number() over (order by nvl2(v, min(o), null)) o, v
             from    ( select t.a, t.b, t.c from dual )
             unpivot include nulls (v for o in (a as 1, b as 2, c as 3))
             group   by v 
          ) 
    pivot (max(v) for o in (1 as a, 2 as b, 3 as c))
  ) l
;
```

**EDIT 2**

In comments after this answer, the OP states that his real-life data has five columns, rather than three. The first solution is hard to extend to five columns, but the second solution is easy to extend. I show how on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=956a69c062fbbf896c0612653a34ede9).

Comment: The second code makes every columns null except the first column. I have five columns in original dataset. Is that not working because of that?

Comment: I'm trying to modify first code for five columns but I do it somehow wrongly.I will really aprreciate If you modify it for five columns.

Comment: @user13619579 - you can't modify the first solution for five columns; I said that in the answer itself. You **should** be able to modify the second solution easily to work for any number of columns. Let me set up a small example on **dbfiddle**, I'll add the link here.

Comment: @user13619579 - see the second edit at the bottom of my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . one method would be to construct a string and then break it apart.  For example:

```
select regexp_substr(str, '[^|]+', 1, 1) as a,
       regexp_substr(str, '[^|]+', 1, 2) as b,
       regexp_substr(str, '[^|]+', 1, 3) as c
from (select t.*,
             trim(leading '|' from
                  (case when a is not null then '|' || a end) ||
                  (case when b is not null then '|' || b end) ||
                  (case when c is not null then '|' || c end)
                 ) str
      from t
     ) t
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=237215c7b90d00134faaa90484af7520) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hmm seems like your table input is the expected output in the fiddle

Comment: You created the output in the input, that's not what I am looking for

Comment: This solution only pushes all the `null` values in each row to the right (it shows the non-`null` values in the left-most columns, as the OP required, but **it does not remove the duplicate values**. Please inspect the OP's explanation and required output. Downvoted as not useful.

Comment: @user13619579 - never mind Gordon's misunderstanding of your input. Take his query and run it on **your** input. You will see that it does do *something* - it does do part of what you requested, but it doesn't do the harder part, which is to remove duplicate values on the same row.